# passing scope to function is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to `angular.js`, and the `$scope` is not working in the function, which is inside the controller....

```
  <div>{{logMsg}}</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      angular.module("app",[] ).controller("myController", function($scope){
          $scope.onConnect = function(status){
          $scope.logMsg = "connecting...";
          } 
          function onMessage(msg) {
            console.log('message');
            $scope.logMsg = "message...";
          }
      });


  </script>
```

The `connecting...` is displayed, but the `message...` is not displayed. But I received the the `message` in the console. What is i'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how is `onMessage` being called? Chances are `$scope` is (ironically) not in scope.

Comment: I think @Jamiec is correct. `$scope.logMsg` in `onMessage` function is not within the scope of the controller.

Comment: From where are you calling on onMessage()?

Comment: actually i'm dealing with `xmpp`, from there it's calling it.. the console is working and not the $scope

Comment: Please add (at least some of) that code to the question? Just need to see the execution flow.

Comment: but the `message...` is not displayed? The `onMessage function` is not even called in your code. Please update the appropriate part.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `$scope` you better inject it using the "array" notation

`angular.module("app",[] ).controller("myController", ['$scope', function($scope){`

Not sure how would you expect the $scope to exist , The function is out of the controller and $scope not injected into the `onMessage` function.

Maybe you meant `onMessage` to be in the controller, or call it from the controller passing the `$scope`?

Comment: You don't have to specify injection like that when you are using inbuilt injections like `$scope` in dev mode - It is good practice, but unless you activate strict mode, it wont changes the anything in context of the question

Comment: Oh but yes, you are right doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: Fixed to answer the problem

Comment: I really don't think this is an injection problem. Nothing would work if that was the case, but it is just a callback that is not updating the scope properly.

Comment: yap I saw my mistake and updated the answer before. but also nitpicking on injection, since without it minification might be broken and he'll be back here

Answer (score 2):

$scope in this case, is `out of scope`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    angular.module("app",[] )
      .controller("myController", function($scope){ <- scope of $scope is from here
          $scope.onConnect = function(status){
             $scope.logMsg = "connecting...";
          } 
      }); <- to here

      function onMessage(msg) {
          console.log('message');
          $scope.logMsg = "message..."; <- no $scope here
      }
 </script>
```

Solution is write onMessage the same way of onConnect. Or assign $scope to another variable which is not recommended.

Comment: Where do you call onMessage?

Answer (score 1):

Your `$scope.logMsg` in `onMessage` is not within the scope of your controller. See correction below.

```
 angular.module("app", []).controller("myController", ['$scope',function($scope) {
   $scope.logMsg = "";
   $scope.onConnect = function(status) {
     $scope.logMsg = "connecting...";
   }
   $scope.onMessage = function(msg) {
     console.log('message');
     $scope.logMsg = "message...";
   };
 }]);
```

Comment: How are you calling the function? if you wish to call `onMessage` in this example from within your controller you will need to do this... `$scope.onMessage('message here!');`. If it is called from a view then you will need to add `ng-click='onMessage("message here!")'`

Comment: actually i'm dealing with xmpp, from there it's calling it.. the console is working and not the $scope

Comment: I'm not familar with xmpp. As for an angular/javascript answer, this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject $scope to `onMessage` function to get the reference of $scope. In this case `$scope` is available only withing the scope of controller method and not inside `onMessage` method.

```js
angular.module("app",[] ).controller("myController", function($scope, $timeout){
          $scope.onConnect = function(status){
          $scope.logMsg = "connecting...";
          } 
          $scope.onConnect();
          $timeout(onMessage($scope), 2000);
      });

          function onMessage($scope) {
            return function(msg){
              console.log('message');
              $scope.logMsg = "message...";
            }            
          }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController">{{logMsg}}</div>
```